# Declaring custom functions on a third party abstract class

Tags: typescript

I need to extend Zod with some custom methods. They don't really have a plugin system so other plugins I've seen use the prototype. This works as intended:

```
z.ZodType.prototype.disabled = function(isDisabled: boolean): ZodType<any, ZodTypeDef, any> {
  this._isDisabled = isDisabled
  return this
}

z.ZodType.prototype.isDisabled = function(): boolean {
  return this._isDisabled
}
```

The problem is that we use Typescript, and the [original ZodType abstract class](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/e6939195fbb5191402ba3d6f5b7aade463de6e51/src/types.ts#L137) obviously doesn't define these extension methods.

I was thinking I could get away with typescript's "interface merging" to extend this, like some other stackoverflow posts recommend, but this isn't an interface - it's an abstract class type.

```
interface ZodType {
  disabled: (isDisabled: boolean) => void
  isDisabled: () => boolean
  _isDisabled: boolean
}
```

This doesn't do anything. Here's an example using my custom function:

```js
const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(3),
  disabled: z.string().disabled(true)
})
```

This errors with "property 'disabled' does not exist on type ZodString" yet ZodString inherits from ZodType

Is there a way I can properly tell typescript about these changes?

Comment: Class declarations declare both a class constructor value and a class instance interface of the same name.  So you would merge into the `ZodType` interface.  Could you possibly [edit] the question to be a self-contained [mre] that doesn't depend on third-party code, unless the question itself depends on zod, in which case, could you tag it as such?  Ideally others could take the code in the question, paste it as-is into an IDE of their choice, and immediately get to work on the issue.

Comment: Anyway, interface merging should definitely work, but when I try like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYLvbm) I see that you are, uh, assigning a boolean to a function?  What's going on there?  Is that the desired behavior?  Are you looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnlQVW) instead?

Comment: Updated the question with a clearer example of what I tried and errors I get. The `this.isDisabled` was a typo, which I fixed.

Comment: @jcatz the `declare module 'zod'` seems to have fixed it... I didn't realize they used that

Comment: Why are you assigning `void` to the `disabled` property, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvqVnm)?  I really wish this were a [mre] without unrelated problems so I could post a nice straightforward answer about module augmentation, but so far I'm still confused. Help!

Comment: That was an oversight. The `disabled` field in the schema needs to be a zod type, I forgot all zod functions return an object. I've updated the example - I don't know exactly which return type I need to be using yet but that at least resolves the error. I couldn't even get far enough to test this code without all the ts errors I started with.

Comment: So then does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyqbAW) resolve everything?  If so I'll write up an answer.

Comment: It resolves my question yes, the module declaration was the piece I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) into the instance side of `class` declarations.  A class declaration like `class Foo { /*...*/ }` brings into scope both the class constructor *value* named `Foo`, and the class instance *interface* named `Foo`, and you can merge into that interface.  This is true for [`abstract` classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members) as well.  So if the class name is `ZodType` then you need to merge into `interface ZodType {}`.

Since that interface is in a module, you're looking for [*module augmentation*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). That's where you `import` a module and then merge your definition into an interface inside an appropriate `declare module` scope.  Like this:

```
import * as z from 'zod';

declare module 'zod' {
    interface ZodType {
        disabled(isDisabled: boolean): this;
        isDisabled(): boolean;
        _isDisabled: boolean
    }
}
```

And now the compiler will know about these definitions, allowing the rest of your code to type check with no errors:

```
z.ZodType.prototype.disabled = function (isDisabled: boolean) {
    this._isDisabled = isDisabled
    return this
}

z.ZodType.prototype.isDisabled = function (): boolean {
    return this._isDisabled
}

const schema = z.object({
    name: z.string().min(3),
    disabled: z.string().disabled(true)
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wF5wGZQiOAcgwgBNCBuAKCtIFMBjAG2SjrhDIFcn3izCcAN5U4YuMAB2MOlGzIG7AFpkAKgE8w7EeN1xSwVMgBGvUgApDAEUMmzALjjGIEXskkBKRzAAWh6nri1ramdBZeTi5ukgGBcAD6wUahpI7OrnTuouIAvlR5VBgAdCqkGlpFYHgwEDCadEUGyWZwALw4XJIMMMAQknCWqDbNYWlRmZ7C2WK+hkWJQyEt7Ul2YdNwbDBcUP2zqPk0xaXlDVW1tfVFqyltHV09fQMR6dFTuls7e36o8zdmhyoDD6qHgqAYPjoIGQd2KEGMACtGDBzDpxJJkCA6I5iqCoFIAObmDxFEBScwAZg8ABoNk01qlMEU8YTiY0lmFzDAoFw6B58h4gA)